# Can I running a pre-existing NextJS app with API routes in a mobile runtime using either Capacitor or Expo?

Tags: javascript, next.js, mobile, expo, capacitor

I've got an existing NextJS app that relies pretty heavily on Next's API routes. I'm trying to convert the existing codebase to run in a mobile environment. I've tried Capacitor and gone through the motions of exporting it as a static site, but when I run it in a mobile environment the requests to Next's API routes fail, which is to be expected I guess because Capacitor only builds the client code.

I'm wondering if there's any way around this though? I've briefly attempted to route the API route requests to a hosted Next instance I have running when it's running as a static site, but the cookie/request validation is failing because of a few issues, mainly when it tries to validate the cookies. I've considered setting up a proxy server, though it seems like a lot of work and Next's built-in proxy configuration doesn't seem to be working for it.

Does anyone know if there's a way in either Capacitor or Expo to build and run the entire Next app(including the API routes) in the same context? As in, having the API routes and static client bits available within the same mobile runtime?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, need to use other route packages Ion  etc. I'm exploring now also. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I will update as I keep exploring, as well